# Domain and sub domain validation using php

Tags: php

```
$domain= "stackexchange.com";
if (checkdnsrr($domain,"MX")){
    echo "yup! " . $domain ." is valid domain";
    }
else{
    echo "nope " . $domain ." invalid domain!";
}
```

I used this code to check whether entered domain is valid or not. Its working
But when i give sub-domain in it, Its says domain not found

```
$domain= "wordpress.stackexchange.com";
    if (checkdnsrr($domain,"MX")){
        echo "yup! " . $domain ." is valid domain";
        }
    else{
        echo "nope " . $domain ." invalid domain!";
    }
```

If i insert this code, its coming as, domain not found.
Does anyone having solution for this??

Comment: A subdomain does not necessarily have an MX record. Check for A records instead.

Comment: @LinusKleen So are A records mandatory? NS records perhaps ?

Comment: @LinusKleen A subdomain or domain doesn't necessarily have A records either. `mail.example.com` might have MX/TXT but no A.

Comment: wordpress.stackexchange.com MX does not return Non-existant domain, btw. It points to cloudflare

Comment: The whole assumption that _having_ an MX record would make a domain generally “valid” is wrong. Before that can even apply, you’d have to define “valid” more specific, less general.

Comment: Thanks @LinusKleen it worked for me, A records worked perfect for me

Answer (score 2):

As the user Linus pointed out, a sub-domain will not necessarily have a `MX` record. Better check for the `A` record.

Even then, a domain might have valid DNS records, yet the site might not be alive.

A better way to check if the site is alive is using [fsockopen()](http://php.net/fsockopen) function.

For example:

```
function isValidSite($url, $port = 80, $timeout = 1) {
    $isValid = false;
    $check = @fsockopen($url, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
    if ($check) {
        $isValid = true;
        @fclose($check);
    }
    return $isValid;
}

var_dump(isValidSite('test.stackexchange.com')); // returns 'true'
```

Even then... this might not be a valid test. Some web servers will implement a catch all rule to re-direct to a 404 page or show a warning, when you try to access a non-existing sub-domain.

Another option is to make a `CURL GET` request and make it return the headers only and check if the response header code is 200 (HTTP OK) to verify if the domain/sub-domain is valid. It's up to you how you want to deal with these various scenarios...